# Get url from the webView in android app

Tags: android, android-webview, android-edittext

i'm trying to get the current url from the webView and save is to the `editField` by using this code :

```
Browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

 Browser.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String url = Browser.getUrl().toString();
         EditText  urlText= (EditText)  findViewById (R.id.urlText);
         urlText.setText(url);

    }
});
```

but its not working please help me out. 
thanks in advance .

Comment: First line makes no sense at the moment. --> Browser mBrowser = (...);

Comment: is this your complete code? because I can see you haven't loaded anything in your webview so far, so no question of getting a URL back. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to get the url `onClick` , you can listen to `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` event of the WebView to get the current url.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() { 
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
                webView.loadUrl(url); 
                // Here the String url hold 'Clicked URL' 
                return false; 
            } 
        });
```

`String url` of the function contains the current url.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Browser` variable has no type. (Or it is not showing in the code).

Your statement `Browser.getUrl().toString()` is redundant, as getUrl() already return a String.

And I don't know if WebView support an `OnClickListener`...